# How can i Convert string to decimal

Tags: c#, string, decimal

I can not convert from string into decimal this is the value of lblTotal="110,00€"
I want to convert it to decimal how can I convert it?

```
decimal number;
if( Decimal.TryParse(((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblTotal")).Text.ToString(), out number))
{

}
```

Comment: i try this but returned false

Comment: problem is € sign, parse string without €

Comment: the question was completely clear .this should not be down voted.

Comment: Avoid headaches text.ToString().replace("€","")

Comment: You may [downvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) question even if they are clear.

Comment: @The_Black_Smurf: So you mean this question is "_an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post_"?

Comment: I didn't downvote... I just mentioned the fact that a clear question may still get downvoted.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't parse your string, there can be a few possibilities..

First of all, `Decimal.TryParse` uses [`NumberStyles.Number`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) style and this does not includes `Currency` style. Both are composite styles. That's why you need to use another overload that specify currency symbol and decimal separator.

Second, your `Decimal.TryParse` uses `CurrentCulture` settings by default. That means, your [`CurrencySymbol`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencysymbol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not `€` and/or your [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not `,`.

As a best solution, you can [`Clone`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.clone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) your `CurrentCulture` and set these properties with `Currency` style like;

```
var clone = (CultureInfo) CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
clone.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "€";
clone.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
decimal number;
if(decimal.TryParse(((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblTotal")).Text, 
                    NumberStyles.Currency, clone, out number))
{
   // You can use number here
}
```

Comment: Nice Soner. Didn't know about the `Clone` method.

Comment: i prefer to use pre defined culture rather than cloning.

Answer (score 2):

You should inform the Decimal.TryParse that you have a currency symbol and what is your culture

```
string test = "110,00€";
if( Decimal.TryParse(test, NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out number))
{
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}
```

I would also recommend to use a more defensive approach to your retrieving of the label to parse.

```
Label lbl = e.Item.FindControl("lblTotal") as Label;
if(lbl != Null)
{
   .....
}
```

Comment: decimal test = decimal.Parse(((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblTotal")).Text, NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);   i write it like this but it gives me Exception

Comment: What are your culture settings? If your CurrentCulture doesn't recognize the Euro symbol as a currency symbol then you should try the code proposed by [Soner Gönül](http://stackoverflow.com/users/447156/soner-g%c3%b6n%c3%bcl)

Comment: @Steve: This seems only to work in an environment with € as the currency sign.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.createspecificculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with culture code of Countries using Euro as currency.

[Table of Language Culture Names, Codes, and ISO Values Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488%28v=cs.20%29.aspx).

for example Greece, Ireland, Italy uses this currency.

Simply

```
decimal resault = decimal.Parse(((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblTotal")).Text.ToString()
                                ,NumberStyles.Currency
                                ,CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("it-IT"));
```

This will convert your string `"110,00€"` to decimal correctly Since Italy uses euro(`€`) as currency.

Or you can use another Culture by searching in the provided link.